# Deserializing a compressed JSON file using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization, nsstream

I would like to parse a compressed JSON file using NSJSONSerialization's method `JSONObjectWithStream:options:error`. How can I decompress the file on-the-fly as stream and use it directly in JSONObjectWithStream:options:error?

Comment: Do you mean gzip compression?

Comment: Yes, gzip or any other compression. I am flexible regarding the compression scheme.

Comment: Why can't you just set the "Content-Encoding" or "Transfer-Encoding" to gzip?

Comment: @Jeffery Thomas, my current backend (parse.com) allows only to store file sizes of 10 MB maximum, my uncompressed JSON file is around 25 MB and compressed 4 MB. That's why I would like to store them as compressed files on the server.

Comment: Obviously what would be ideal is a stream unzipper.  Dunno if there is one available, however.  Otherwise you'll need to unzip and then parse the resulting NSData, as two separate steps.  There are several unzip packages available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### gzip

[NSDataCategory](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSDataCategory) is a bit rough, but it will handle inflating gzipped files.

### PK Zip

[ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) and [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) will unzip a zipped archive.